# Why can't I replace if statement with conditional operator (?:)?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I've been struggling to turn

```
private PlaneClass preferredClass;

if (preferredClass == PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS)
    preferredClass = PlaneClass.ECONOMY_CLASS;
else
    preferredClass = PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS;
```

into

```
preferredClass == PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS ? 
                preferredClass = PlaneClass.ECONOMY_CLASS 
                               : preferredClass = PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS;
```

The if-statement **compiles**.
The conditional operator **doesn't**. (Error messages: 1. Type mismatch: cannot convert from PlaneClass to boolean 2. syntax error on token "=". And two other error...). Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
condition ? value1 : value2;
```

not

```
condition ? statement1 : statement2;
```

The conditional operator is an expression, not a statement. It doesn't execute statements like an `if` statement does: it returns a value.

What you mean is:

```
preferredClass = (preferredClass == PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS ? 
            PlaneClass.ECONOMY_CLASS : PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS);
```

Comment: That's a basic distinction, which I somehow overlooked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
preferredClass = preferredClass == PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS ? PlaneClass.ECONOMY_CLASS : PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS;
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
preferredClass == PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS ? 
             PlaneClass.ECONOMY_CLASS 
                           :  PlaneClass.FIRST_CLASS;
```